# r code doesn't run. Need for optimization

Tags: r, optimization

For a dataframe (df) containing more than 750.000 observations I want to run a piece of code similar to the one below. However, when executing it, it keeps running for more than 6 hours without any result (no error message though). Is there a way to optimize the code?

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(W,X,Y,Z) %>% 
  summarise(total = length(unique(ID)))
```

Comment: Try `data.table` : `setDT(df)[, .(total = uniqueN(ID)), .(W,X,Y,Z)]`

Comment: I fully agree with @Ronak Shah, data.table is much more efficient. If you want to stay in dplyr, perhaps try its [parallel version](https://github.com/tidyverse/multidplyr)

Comment: There's also a data.table backend package for dplyr. I've not tried it out as I use data.table mostly, but may help https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr